# Differential equation with a unknown function $g$ but a known solution.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Say we have an equation $y'+g(x)y=3x, x>0$.

- We know **one** solution to this FDE: $y(x) = x^2$

How can we know if there's a solution which satisfies $y(1) = 2$?

---

Questions I'd like answered

- Q1: First and foremost, how do I go about solving the problem I have listed?
- Q2: If I understand correctly, this is a *first-order linear ordinary differential equation*. However, is there any known term for the problem I have, where you have an unknown function $g(x)$.
- Q3: Is $g(x)$ to be considered a coefficient for our differential equation (where we are searching for $y$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1:** For this type of problem, you have for a fact that one solution is $y(x) = x^2$ which gives you that $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$. Using this in your equation, you can solve for $g(x)$.

$$2x+g(x)\cdot x^2 = 3x \iff g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

Now, using $g(x)$, you solve for $y$ by the method you used.

$$y' + \frac{y}{x}=3x$$

Multiply by $e^{\int g(x)} = e^{\ln x} = x$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
xy'+y&=&3x^2 \\
D(xy) &=& 3x^2 \\
xy &=& \int 3x^2 = 3\int x^2 = x^3 + C \\
y &=& x^2 + \frac{C}{x}
\end{eqnarray}$$

In the question, we had the initial value $y(1) = 2$, and as such we get:

$$2 = 1^2+\frac{C}{1} = 1+C \iff C = 1$$

The sought-after function is $\boxed{y(x) = x^2+ \frac{1}{x}}$

**A2:** *Couldn't find any name for it.*

**A3:** *Still don't know.*